# django database dynamically chosen based on part of the domain name

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I am creating a Django project which could be useful for many small companies. I would like it if they could click on a "Create Demo" button on my public page which creates an empty database for the Django project.

So, I would like to be able to go to http://example.com/demo_a  or http://example.com/demo_b but have only one entry in the Apache configuration file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/example/mysite.wsgi

    <Directory var/www/example>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't really want to have to go into the http.conf file each time I want to create a demo site.  So, I am alright if they have to go to http://example.com/demo_a (for example).

What is not clear to me is how to associate the "demo_a" to a database. There is the Database Router stuff and the Sites stuff, but I don't see how I would choose a database (or "site") based on some part of the URL (e.g., "demo_a").

On a side note, I am storing static files in S3 in a directory determined dynamically so static files I think I can deal with.

This whole thing could be useful for doing load balancing too.

I am new at much of this level of Django.  Any ideas? It seems like it should work just not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is not new, but a common one for anyone creating any multi-tenant software; or developing a software-as-a-service application.

*For a more detailed analysis on the data challenges associated with such an architecture, I highly recommend reading [this excellent article from 2006 from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx).*

The [`django-tenant-schemas` application](http://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) provides view routing so that domains are correctly routed to their individual databases:

> Tenants are identified via their host name (i.e tenant.domain.com).
>   This information is stored on a table on the public schema. Whenever a
>   request is made, the host name is used to match a tenant in the
>   database. If there’s a match, the search path is updated to use this
>   tenant’s schema. So from now on all queries will take place at the
>   tenant’s schema. For example, suppose you have a tenant customer at
>   http://customer.example.com. Any request incoming at
>   customer.example.com will automatically use customer‘s schema and make
>   the tenant available at the request. If no tenant is found, a 404
>   error is raised. This also means you should have a tenant for your
>   main domain, typically using the public schema.